# Changing attribute dynamically of a svg element using setTimeout doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to move an SVG to, say, X,Y by having a `setTimeout` call the `moveSelected` function recursively. The `moveSelected` function in turn sets the new x and y a little closer to X,Y to reproduce the animation effect.

Here is my function:

```
this.moveSelected = function moveSelected(moveToHex) {
    //setting new cords on screen
    var self=this;
    var repeater;

    var curX = parseInt(this.selectedEle.getAttribute('cx'));
    var curY = parseInt(this.selectedEle.getAttribute('cy'));

    //console.log('curX '+curX+'curY ',curY);
    if(curX < moveToHex.cx) //moveRight
    {
        this.selectedEle.setAttribute('cx', curX + .5);
    }

    if(curX > moveToHex.cx) //moveLeft
    {
        this.selectedEle.setAttribute('cx',curX-.5);
    }

    if(curY < moveToHex.cy) //movedown
    {
        console.log('move down');
        this.selectedEle.setAttribute('cy', curY + .5);
    }

    if(curY > moveToHex.cy) //moveup
    {
        console.log('move Up');
        this.selectedEle.setAttribute('cy', curY - .5);
    }

    console.log('condition:' + curY + '<' + parseInt(moveToHex.cy));

    if((Math.abs(curY - moveToHex.cy)) < 1 &&
       (Math.abs(curX - moveToHex.cx) < 1)) {
        clearTimeout(repeater);
        unitArray[this.selectedUnit.num].hexagon = moveToHex;
        console.log('cleared');
    }
    else if(!repeater) {
        repeater = setTimeout(function() {
            self.moveSelected(moveToHex)
        }, 25); 
    }
}
```

Now everything works as expected but the movedown and moveRight conditions, i.e. `curY + .5` and `curX + .5`.

I tried consoling out the values but don't understand why it is behaving like that. I assumed it is typecasting problem but typecasting as `curX` and `curY` into int didn't help either

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Snedden27/z4xfy6n8/2/ (scroll to the two movable circles at the right)

Comment: `don't understand why it is behaving like that` ... like what? don't make us guess

Comment: I meant why won't it add  0.5 to curX or curY while subtraction works

Comment: this is like pulling teeth ... what does it do instead?

Comment: yes, it's because you parseInt that it behaves that way - don't parseInt

Comment: damm! that was stupid and I am embarrassed , 
Thanks